# What are the possible datatypes that can be return from asp.net webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, types

What are the possible datatypes that can be return from asp.net webservice.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean asmx, then:

- pretty much any of the inbuilt primitives and standard data types
- `Stream` / `byte[]`
- arrays, or lists / collections with obvious semantics
- xml-serializable types:

  - public types with public parameterless constructors and public properties/fields (optionally attributed for more control)
  - public types that implement `IXmlSerializable`

For WCF, add data-contracts to that list.

Answer (score 0):

All primitives including String can be returned with no special code requried. Otherwise you must use [data contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) (if you are using WCF) or more powerful [XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx) API.

Comment: Can a HashTable be returned from asmx webservice

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return any type of data from a web service including hashtable too..